# Postfix not delivering mails

Tags: postfix

I have problems with a recently configured postfix MTA.
When postfix starts the following warning appears:

```
postfix/qmgr[5078]: warning: connect to transport private/filter: No such file or directory
```

I have amavis-new as a content-filter, but even if I comment-out the relevant line, the warning appears.
As a result (I think), of the above, I get errors like below, for every virtual domain that I have:

```
postfix/error[5080]: 254851834107: to=<info@domainname.com>, relay=none, delay=13082, delays=13082/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

The good news for me, is that somehow I managed to fix that (don't ask
me how!!!!)

The problem is that now I have 50 or so mails, that were affected by the
aforementioned problem, in the mail-queue... If I `postqueue -f` I get
the same style of error as before

```
mail transport
unavailable
```

However new mails are delivered to their final
destination properly...

Any suggestions?

Kind regards.

P.S.
Local mail delivery from/to Unix and virtual users, was OK write from the beginning!

Answer (score 12):

SOLVED:  `postsuper -r ALL` did the job....

Comment: So do I have to run this command on a regular basis?

Comment: This solved my issue!
I had to do a `postsuper -r ALL && postqueue -f` to solve the problem.
This is a life-saver command

Answer (score 1):

That error message indicates `postfix` is trying to use a transport named `private/filter`, which should be defined in `master.cf`. Do you have a line starting with that in `master.cf`? If not, you should either add it or change whatever points to it in your `main.cf`.

Comment: Hi,
I never had the phrase 'private/filter' or 'filter' in neither master.cf nor main.cf The only close match is content_filter and "smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth" but that have nothing to do...
However, I think I fixed it (I changed mydomain and myorigin directives)...but now I have a new problem (see my original post)...

Answer (score 0):

When you get `(mail transport unavailable)` the real error will be someway further back up the `/var/log/mail.log`.  postfix will try a few deliveries and then this error means it knows further attempts will fail so doesn't bother. Try postfix check to see if there are any errors.  If you change files in `/etc/postfix` you may need to run `postmap` on the file to update it. I was getting `SASL auth failed` even though I had edited my `/etc/postix/sasl_passwd` file because I had not run `postmap sasl_passwd` afterwards to create the `sasl_passwd.db` file that postfix was actually using for the auth.

Comment: Your answer is very hard to read (e.g. " postfix will try a few deliveries and then this error means it knows further attempts will fail so doesn't bother.")